# Why do I get this exception (gRCP)

Tags: c#, streaming, rpc

I try to do a BlackJack game in gRPC to practice, but I don't understand this stream transfer.

Task(Server):

```
public async Task Deal(Amount dealAmount, IServerStreamWriter<Card> responseStream, ServerCallContext context)
    {
        this.dealAmount = int.Parse(dealAmount.ToString());
        if (deck.Count < 17)
        {
            deck.Clear();
            DeckRead();
            Shuffle();
        }

        FirstDeal();

        Card temp = new Card();
        temp.Card_ = player[0];
        await responseStream.WriteAsync(temp);
        temp.Card_ = player[1];
        await responseStream.WriteAsync(temp);
        temp.Card_ = dealer[0];
        await responseStream.WriteAsync(temp);
    }
```

Client:

```
private async void btDeal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Amount dAmount = new Amount();
        dAmount.Amount_ = Convert.ToInt32(udDeal.Value);
        string newCard;

        using (var call = client.Deal(dAmount))
        {
            var responseStream = call.ResponseStream;
            int y = 0;
            while (await responseStream.MoveNext())
            {
                newCard = responseStream.Current.ToString();

                if(y == 3)
                {
                    dealer.Add(newCard);
                }
                else
                {
                    player.Add(newCard);
                    y++;
                }
            }
        }

        dealerCards[0].Load(string.Format("Images/cards/{0}.png", dealer[0]));
        dealerCards[1].Load(string.Format("Images/cards/Back/gray_back.png"));
        playerCards[0].Load(string.Format("Images/cards/{0}.png", player[0]));
        playerCards[1].Load(string.Format("Images/cards/{0}.png", player[1]));

        lblDealerAmount.Text = int.Parse(dealer[0].Substring(0, 2)).ToString();
        lblPlayerAmount.Text = PlayerAmount().ToString();

        money = money - dealAmount;
        lblAmount.Text = money.ToString();
        btDeal.Enabled = false;
    }
```

proto:

```
rpc Deal(Amount) returns (stream Card) {}

message Card {
   string card=1;
}

message Amount {
  int32 amount=1;
}
```

I know that this is not the cleanest code ever, but for now I just want to understand how gRCP is working. So this task would deal the first four card, two to the player, two to the dealer but one of the dealer's card with the back, so the client will get three Card (2 of his card and 1 is the dealer's card what he can see).

First of all, I get an exception at *while (await responseStream.MoveNext())* , because of the input parameters, but don't know what is the wrong.

RpcException:

*An exception of type 'Grpc.Core.RpcException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Status(StatusCode=Unknown, Detail="Exception was thrown by handler.")*

In the server's console:

```
E02/01/2019 13:46:47 Grpc.Core.Internal.ServerStreamingServerCallHandler`2 Exception occured in handler. System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info)
   at System.Int32.Parse(String s)
   at BlackJackServer.BJS.<Deal>d__14.MoveNext() in C:\Users\tesa3\Desktop\GRPC BEAD\grpc\grpc-master\examples\csharp\BlackJack\BlackJackServer\Program.cs:line 108
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Grpc.Core.Internal.ServerStreamingServerCallHandler`2.<HandleCall>d__0.MoveNext()
```

From the otherside I dont know that I use *WriteAsync* properly in this case. I mean I exactly know the client will get three string. Can I just read the current, and then *MoveNext* and read again and so on?

Comment: Where is the exception?

Comment: Editet, but I guess it won't be enough, in the console I got more information, just on my own language but I try to set it to English.

Comment: I do not understand it either!!!  You have an async method Deal() that is reading a stream with NO protocol.  You cannot process a request/response without having a complete message or code that makes sure.  The Deal Code is writing three objects and it is going to take time to send the message from the client to the server and for the server to respond.  Meanwhile the client stream is at the end and doing a read before the response is valid will fail because you are at the EOF.  The client has to wait for full response from the server before processing the response.

Comment: @DominikS Edited with the full error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a problem in your code that's mostly unrelated to gRPC.

From the error message it's obvious that it's happening inside the server-side handler. Let's take a look there.

The very first line there is `int.Parse(dealAmount.ToString());`,  the "dealAmount" is a protocol buffer message, and ToString() gives its JSON representation (e.g. something like `{ "Value": 123 }` or so). This clearly has not the format that int.Parse can accept (hence the exception "System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.").

Converting to a protobuf message to string and then trying to parse makes no sense  - the generated "Amount" class already gives you access to all the fields you need, with the right type.

Comment: Actually I get over it, and now my program is working, but I forget what was the problem here what I solved, because later I had more trouble. Thanks for your answer!